# Delete Events from Google Calendar based on Google Sheets using Google Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-calendar-api, google-sheets-api

Absolute noob here !

**Background:**

- am trying to create a Google Sheet which I can update for a series of events and
- create Google Calendar events based on those entries
- so far, am successful in creating calendar events and also updating back the last column of the sheet with the EventID (iCalUID) - thanks to other stackoverflow posts
- am also successful in not creating Duplicates by checking if the EventID (iCalUID) is already present in the last column - thanks again to other stackoverflow posts

**But... have another requirement, where am failing:**

- need to mark an existing event as 'Cancelled' in one of the columns in the sheet and
- if this is 'true' then look-up the EventID (iCalUID) from the corresponding last cell (of that row which has a 'Cancelled' entry) and
- delete that particular event from the calendar
- also, calendar events should NOT be created again as long as that cell remains/retains the word 'Cancelled'.
- the "var check1 = row[23];  //Booked/Blocked/Cancelled" in below script was just added to bring in this logic that I wanted, but am kind of unable to proceed

[Relevant screen-shot of the sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mt9QN.jpg)

Code that I used so far as below:

```
function onOpen() {
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  ui.createMenu('Sync to Calendar')
  .addItem('Sync Now', 'sync')
  .addToUi();
}

function sync() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  var calendar = CalendarApp.getCalendarById('myemailid@gmail.com');
  var startRow = 2;  // First row from which data should process > 2 exempts my header row
  var numRows = sheet.getLastRow();   // Number of rows to process
  var numColumns = sheet.getLastColumn();
  var dataRange = sheet.getRange(startRow, 1, numRows-1, numColumns);
  var data = dataRange.getValues();

  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; ++i) {
    var row = data[i];
    var name = row[1];  //Name of Guest
    var place = row[4];  //Add2
    var room = row[9]; //Room Number    
    var inDate = new Date(row[10]);  //Check-In Date
    var outDate = new Date(row[11]); //Check-Out Date
    var check1 = row[23];  //Booked/Blocked/Cancelled
    var check2 = row[24]; //Event created and EventID (iCalUID) populated 
    
   if (check2 == "") {
      var currentCell = sheet.getRange(startRow + i, numColumns);
      var event = calendar.createEvent(room, inDate, outDate, {
      description: 'Booked by: ' + name + ' / ' + place + '\nFrom: ' + inDate + '\nTo: ' + outDate
      });
      var eventId = event.getId();
      currentCell.setValue(eventId);
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe your goal is as follows.

- You want to check the columns "X" and "Y".
- When the column "X" is not `Cancelled` and the column "Y" is empty, you want to create a new event.
- When the column "X" is `Cancelled` and the column "Y" is not empty, you want to delete the existing event.
- When the column "X" is `Cancelled`, you don't want to create a new event.

In this case, how about the following modification?

#### Modified script:

In this script, in order to check whether the event has already been deleted, Calendar API is used. So [please enable Calendar API at Advanced Google services](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/advanced#enable_advanced_services).

```js
function sync() {
  var calendarId = 'myemailid@gmail.com'; // Please set your calendar ID.

  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  var calendar = CalendarApp.getCalendarById(calendarId);
  var startRow = 2;  // First row from which data should process > 2 exempts my header row
  var numRows = sheet.getLastRow();   // Number of rows to process
  var numColumns = sheet.getLastColumn();
  var dataRange = sheet.getRange(startRow, 1, numRows - 1, numColumns);
  var data = dataRange.getValues();
  var done = "Done";  // It seems that this is not used.
  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; ++i) {
    var row = data[i];
    var name = row[1];  //Name of Guest
    var place = row[4];  //Add2
    var room = row[9]; //Room Number    
    var inDate = new Date(row[10]);  //Check-In Date
    var outDate = new Date(row[11]); //Check-Out Date
    var check1 = row[23];  //Booked/Blocked/Cancelled
    var check2 = row[24]; //Event created and EventID (iCalUID) populated 
    
    // I modified below script.
    if (check1 != "Cancelled" && check2 == "") {
      var currentCell = sheet.getRange(startRow + i, numColumns);
      var event = calendar.createEvent(room, inDate, outDate, {
        description: 'Booked by: ' + name + ' / ' + place + '\nFrom: ' + inDate + '\nTo: ' + outDate
      });
      var eventId = event.getId();
      currentCell.setValue(eventId);
    } else if (check1 == "Cancelled" && check2 != "") {
      var status = Calendar.Events.get(calendarId, check2.split("@")[0]).status;
      if (status != "cancelled") {
        calendar.getEventById(check2).deleteEvent();
      }
    }
  }
}
```

#### Reference:

- [Events: get](https://developers.google.com/calendar/api/v3/reference/events/get)

Comment: Brilliant !! I have no words to Thank You enough !!
Your edit worked like a charm !
This was indeed a great learning for me 
- I had seen some posts with the && Logic, Delete Event by iCalUID using the .split("@") etc. 
- But somehow was not able to create a working code combining all these.... Thanks a ton again !
I need at least 15 reputation to cast a vote, but  please accept my heartfelt gratitude :-)

Comment: @Abecedarian Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. Thank you, too.

Comment: Wish to seek your kind help once again !  Has anything changed with Google Calendar API / Apps Script recently ? Am asking this because, in the same code that you modified for me, used to work flawlessly, but off late, the loop stops at the first (top to down) 'Cancelled' event in the sheet and throws an error saying "Exception: The calendar event does not exist, or it has already been deleted." and fails to process any further.  I have found a way to overcome this error by deleting the  'calendarId' from the last column (row[24]) after a 'deleteEvent' is performed.

Comment: Is there any better way to continue the loop without manually deleting the 'calendarId' after a Cancellation ? Thank you in advance :-)

Comment: @Abecedarian I would like to support you. But the issue of replying is new issue, and that is different from your question. So can you post it as new question? Because when your initial question is changed by comment, other users who see your question are confused. By posting it as new question, users including me can think of it. If you can cooperate to resolve your new issue, I'm glad. Can you cooperate to resolve your new question?